# How to do a Merge Request on Bitbucket?

Tags: merge, bitbucket

I have a Spring Boot project and I need to do the merge request for my branch. Until now I used GitLab, and it is very easy to do the merge request on GitLab, I just click the branches and then click the Merge Request button for a specific branch. But now I need to use Bitbucket and I can't find the Merge Request button. Can someone explain me how to do merge request for my branch dlp-1234 with master? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I believe non GitLab platforms call it a pull request, including Bitbucket:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-a-pull-request-to-merge-your-change/